# postNotification trigger the function correctly , but userinfo(NSDictionary) has nothing

Tags: iphone

I used the codes below to notify the menu selection index

```
    NSDictionary *userInfo=  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"123"] 
                                              forKey:@"Index"];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"notifyToMenuSelectionNotification"
                                                    object: userInfo];



-(void)menuSelectionNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  NSLog(@"%@", notification.userInfo);


}
```

menuSelectionNotification is triggered correctly,

but NSLog output notification.userInfo is still {null}

Welcome any comment1

Comment: Now you have three duplicate answers - choose a random one to solve your problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are passing object in wrong way. Please try this -

```
NSDictionary *userInfo=  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"123"] 
                                              forKey:@"Index"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notifyToMenuSelectionNotification"
                                      object:nil
                                      userInfo:userInfo];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your dictionary as the userInfo parameter, not as the object. You may want to try

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notifyToMenuSelectionNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post the dictionary in `userInfo` parameter , like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notifyToMenuSelectionNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

For more detail, pl. see the [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notifyToMenuSelectionNotification" object:userInfo userInfo:nil];

-(void)menuSelectionNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
NSDictionary *userInfo =   (NSDictionary*)notification.object;
}
```